# Bounding the error on $\textbf{y}' = A\textbf{y}$ with $\textbf{y}(0) = \textbf{y}_0$ using Eulers Method.

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In this case $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Now I have deduced the bound,

$$||e_n||_2=||\textbf{y}(nh) - \textbf{y}_0||_2\leq||y_0||_2|(1+h\lambda_M)^n - e^{nh\lambda_M}|$$

where $\lambda_M = ||A||_2$. I obtained this by bounding the error for $n=1$ and $n=2$, it involved quite a bit of algebra but there was a pattern emerging. To verify it I used induction. Now, I had a look in my text book and the upper bound is,

$$||e_n||_2\leq||y_0||_2 \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}|(1+h\lambda)^n - e^{nh\lambda}| \quad (**)$$
where $\sigma(A)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$,
this is a different result but I hope I can relate them. I would like to say that
$$|(1+h\lambda_M)^n - e^{nh\lambda_M}| \leq \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}|(1+h\lambda)^n - e^{nh\lambda}|$$

However I am having trouble establishing this as $\lambda_M$ is an absolute value of an eigenvalue and so not necessarily an eigenvalue.

EDIT:

Perhaps they can not be related like I have asked. I can not seem to derive $(**)$ directly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that the difference vector is
$$
{\bf y}(nh)-{\bf y}_n=e^{nh{\bf A}}{\bf y}_0-(I+h{\bf A})^n{\bf y}_0=f({\bf A}){\bf y}_0
$$
As with all analytic functions, if the domain of convergence of $f$ includes the spectrum of $A$, then the spectrum of $f(A)$ is the image under $f$ of the spectrum of $A$.

In the case of a symmetric matrix $A$, $f(A)$ is symmetric as well and the spectral or operator norm equals the spectral radius. Thus
$$
\|f({\bf A}){\bf y}_0\|_2\le\|f({\bf A})\|_{op}\,\|{\bf y}_0\|_2=\max_{λ\in σ(A)}|f(λ)|\;\|{\bf y}_0\|_2
$$

Your bound is only valid if you can guarantee that $A$ is positive semi-definite and $f$is monotonous so that the maximum over some interval is always at the boundary.

Comment: I shall have to look through my solution to see where I have assumed that $A$ is a positive semi-definite. I can not remember assuming this. But you solution is just so much more elegant!

Comment: I should have added that I was not told to assume that A is positive semi-definite! Where does this knowledge come from btw? specifically  if the domain of convergence of 
f
f
includes the spectrum of 
A
A
, then the spectrum of 
f(A)
f(A)
is the image under 
f
f
of the spectrum of 
A??

Comment: See [wikipedia: Matrix function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function) or general spectral analysis. This fact about matrix functions is valid for all matrices, not only the diagonalizable ones. If $f(z)=\sum c_kz^k$ and $A=SJS^{-1}$, where $J$ is the Jordan normal form, then $f(A)=Sf(J)S^{-1}$ and $f(J)=\sum c_kJ^k$ is an upper triangular matrix where the diagonal entries are the function values of the diagonal entries of $J$.